# nodejs, jade multiple inheritance doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, pug

I have multiple levels on inheritance,

**test-layout.jade**

```
html
  head
    title My Site - #{title}
  body
    block content
    block foot
      #footer
        p some footer content
```

**test.jade**

```
extends test-layout

block content
  h1 titllllllllle
  p some text
```

**test-child.jade**

```
extends test

block content
  .sidebar
    li
      block sidebar
        p nothing
  .primary
    li
      block primary
        p nothing
```

**test-grandson**

```
extend test-child

block sidebar
  b this is grandson sidebar

block primary
  b this is grandson primary
```

type `http://*/test`

I got this problem:

```
500 Error: F:\express\views\test\test-layout.jade:2
1| extends test-layout
> 2|
3| block content
4| h1 my titllllllllle
5| p some text unexpected token "indent"
```

type `http://*/test-child`

I got this:

```
extends test-layout

nothing

nothing
```

Anyone could help out?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally forked jade project at github and submitted a fix here:

https://github.com/kiinoo/jade.git

I also sent a [pull request](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1163) to jade code owner, hope they could integrate it soon.

Answer (score 1):

At first you could correct the type in `test-grandson.jade` (`extend` to `extends`). Nethertheless a new Jade-Version should handle this. Which Version are you using?

I'm running Jade 0.34.1 on Windows 7 64bit and got this result, which is what I expected:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site - </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <li><b>this is grandson sidebar</b></li>
    </div>
    <div class="primary">
      <li><b>this is grandson primary</b></li>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>some footer content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

The problem originated in the encoding of aaron's file. His files where encoded with UTF-8 and got the [UTF-8 BOM Mark](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) appended by his editor. Obviously Jade can't handle this mark well, although that isn't a Jade problem in particular but more of a Node.js problem.

You can get a workaround with adding an empty line in the beginning of your problematic file. Otherwise you will have to find a way to strip the BOM Mark from your files, which isn't trivial.

(There is already an [issue on the Jade GitHub repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/235))

Comment: Thanks Zeeker, I changed extend to extends, but still got the problem. 

I tried to update jade from 0.33.* to 0.34.1, still failed

Comment: In which enviroment are you using Jade? I wrote a small Express app and it continued to work fine.

Comment: I'm using win7 x64, express 3.3.4, jade 0.34.1. I created a little app too, could you help me take a look at? I uploaded it to skydrive public folder here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AB903786598CFD70!105&authkey=!AJuqPRyLClvxZBo, I added a route method in app.js like this `app.get('/test', function(req,res){
  res.render('test');
});`, is this why it failed?

Comment: @aaron Well, I just downloaded your stuff and tried to run it and I recieved exactly the same error you did.  
Now comes the strange part: I switched your `test-layout.jade` with mine and it worked fine, although the content was identical. My `test-layout.jade` file was 3 byte smaller (for what reason ever).  
As crazy as it sounds, I would suggest you to delete your old test-layout file and create a new "fresh" one with the same contents. It worked for me.

Comment: I got it, it is encoding problem, my encoding is utf8, yours should be ansi, if the layout file is ansi then it won't be rendered! thanks very much for taking time and found the problem. I will try to search google for a solution, since my layout file contains some non-ansi chinese characters, i should use utf8 now.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help. :)

I'll edit the solution in my answer so other people can see it more easily.

Comment: @aaron I got it. It's the [UTF-8 BOM](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) which is prepended by many Windows editors. This isn't in particular a Jade problem. You can make a workaround with putting a empty line in the beginning of your layout file!